# angularjs filtering with exact match returns null values in latest versions

Tags: angularjs, filter

Myself have a angularjs sample with [filters here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/y07qtwj6/) where i can filter the values with exact match using the `true` comparator as,

```
 <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{name: name, phone: phone} : true">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
            <td>{{user.secret}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

It works great with combination filters when using angularjs version `1.1.5` where as it returns null for other angularjs versions when user filters and return back to `--select--` position.

Reference: [with angularjs 1.1.5](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/y07qtwj6/1/)
, [with angularjs 1.4.x](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/y07qtwj6/)

Comment: update all code with js

Comment: Already given the fiddles. Please refer. I wanted to know is it bug in angularjs  because i hope it should work in later versions also or anything i had missed out in new versions?

Comment: see answer it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can see updated [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y07qtwj6/2/). It is working fine as your requirement. I have updated AngularJS 1.4.8 in javascript.

**HTML Code**

```
<div ng-app="plunker">
```

```
Name:  <select ng-model="name">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="John1">John1</option>
  <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
</select>
Phone:  <select ng-model="phone">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="555-1276">555-1276</option>
</select>
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{name: name, phone: phone} : true">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{user.secret}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 


 $scope.users = [{name:'John1', phone:'555-1276', secret:'shhh'},
                           {name:'John1', phone:'800-BIG-MARY', secret:'psst'},
                           {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321', secret:'shhh'},
                           {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678', secret:'shhh'},
                           {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765', secret:'shhh'}];
});
```

Comment: It works because there is external angularjs v 1.1.5 resource. Please remove and check once.

Comment: if i remove angularjs resource then how can work filter

Comment: See the given reference in question. ref one: uses angularjs version 1.1.5 as external files at LHS of fiddle. Ref 2 uses angularjs 1.4.8 within fiddle without external resource.

Answer (score 0):

Match with user.name not name as you are using `ng-repeat = "user in users"` .